# linking error from compiling a cython code calling extern library

Tags: c, visual-c++, cython

i have compiled a C module called [edlib](https://github.com/Martinsos/edlib) for edit distance, then i included it in my project,

```
setup.py
structureS.pyx
cedlib.pxd
cedlib
|_____include
      |______edlib.h
|_____lib
      |______edlib.lib
```

but after running `python setup build_ext --inplace` i have linking error , here is the code ,

```
#file:setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "structureS",
        ["structureS.pyx"],
        extra_compile_args=['/openmp'],
        extra_link_args=['/openmp'],
        include_dirs = ['edlib/include'],
        #libraries = ['edlib'],
        library_dirs = ['edlib/lib'],
        # sources = ['edlib/src/edlibe.cpp']

    )
]
setup(
    name='structureS',
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
)
```

the pxd file was given by the author of the module in this link [cedlib.pxd](https://github.com/Martinsos/edlib/blob/master/bindings/python/cedlib.pxd)

```
#structureS.pyx
from cedlib cimport EdlibAlignResult, edlibAlign, edlibDefaultAlignConfig,edlibFreeAlignResult

cdef char* query = "ACCTCTG"
cdef char* target = "ACTCTGAAA"
cdef EdlibAlignResult result = edlibAlign(query, 7, target, 9, edlibDefaultAlignConfig())
if (result.status == 0): #EDLIB_STATUS_OK
    printf("%d", result.editDistance)

edlibFreeAlignResult(result)
```

here is the error message:

> structureS.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu edlibFreeAlignResult
>
> structureS.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu edlibAlign
>
> structureS.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu
>   edlibDefaultAlignConfig

note: my project is compiled for 64bit platform , and the module is given configured for 32bit platform, i have tried to compile the module for 64bit with visual studio 2017 without success ,

Comment: why you commented `libraries = ['edlib'],` line?

Comment: because before i have copied the header file and the library file to the compiler folder so i have used  `libraries = ['edlib']` , but with the linking errors , i have copied the files to a folder named edlib as shown in the question above , and i commented the line you mentioned , i think its the same in both cases, so the problem isn't from that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved it, by compiling directly the C module source with the cython source , here is the solution

```
#file:setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
ext_modules = [
    Extension("structureS",
         ["structureS.pyx", "edlib/src/edlib.cpp"],
         include_dirs=["edlib/include"],
         depends=["edlib/include/edlib.h"],
        extra_compile_args=['/openmp'],
        extra_link_args=['/openmp'],
    )
]
setup(
    name='structureS',
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
)
```